# If request path is already exist what should i do for redirecting url with 301?

Tags: magento-1.9, 301-redirect

`How to rewrite URL with 301 redirecting` if request path and id already exist.

There is any other option to do that or can we do with `.htaccess file`?

Comment: yes possible using .htaccess file.

Comment: can uh tell me the steps plz...i have some bulk urls.

Comment: Please use this in .htaccess on Magento root folder. Redirect 301 /blog/post/abc https://www.example.com/yourpath

Comment: But i have some category urls.so how to do that?

Comment: Same as my above comment. **Redirect 301 /old_category_request_path /new_category_full_path**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do using .htaccess file

Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile.htm

Hope it will help you.